# Rails 5: Two forms for one polymorphic model on a single view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, erb, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a polymorphic model, `Comment`, comment on a `Post` or another `Comment` (reddit style). I want a user to be able to comment directly to the post with a `commentable_id` of `@post.id` and a `commentable_type` of `@post.class.name`

OR

be able to comment on another comment on the same page, however, using `@comment.id` and `@comment.class.name`

Is there a way to dynamically change between `@post` or `@comment` depending on where the form is?

Here is the relevant information that I think might help.

My Form

```
# shared/_comment_form.html.erb
<div id="comment-form" class="form-group">
  <%= form_for @comment, remote: true, url: post_comments_path(@post) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, required: true, rows: 5, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_id, :value => @post.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_type, :value => @post.class.name %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<span id="add-comment">Add a comment</span>
```

And my view

```
# show.html.erb for a Post
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h2>Post:</h2>
<div class="well">
  <p>
    <strong>Title:</strong>
    <%= @post.title %>
  </p>
<% if @post.description %>
  <p>
    <strong>Description:</strong>
    <%= @post.description %>
  </p>
<% end %>
</div>

<%= render "shared/comment_form" %>

<% if @post.comments.any? %>
  <%= render "shared/comment_list" %> # Inside of this partial will be another comment form for the a comment.
<% else %>
  <p>No comments yet</p>
<% end %>
```

Inside the `comment_list` partial would be another partial of `comment_form`

```
# shared/_comment_list.html.erb
<h2>Comments</h2>
<ul>
  <% @post.comments.each do |c| %>
    <li><%= c.body %></li>
      <%= render "shared/comment_form" %> # Here
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

EDIT:

I'm adding my routes too.

```
# Applicable routes 
resources :forums do
  resources :posts,     shallow: true do
    resources :comments,  shallow: true
  end
end
```

And:

```
post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     comments#index
                     POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     comments#create
new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format) comments#new
        edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)           comments#edit
             comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)                comments#show
                     PATCH  /comments/:id(.:format)                comments#update
                     PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)                comments#update
                     DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)                comments#destroy
         forum_posts GET    /forums/:forum_id/posts(.:format)      posts#index
                     POST   /forums/:forum_id/posts(.:format)      posts#create
      new_forum_post GET    /forums/:forum_id/posts/new(.:format)  posts#new
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)              posts#edit
                post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#show
                     PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#update
                     PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#update
                     DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#destroy
              forums GET    /forums(.:format)                      forums#index
                     POST   /forums(.:format)                      forums#create
           new_forum GET    /forums/new(.:format)                  forums#new
          edit_forum GET    /forums/:id/edit(.:format)             forums#edit
               forum GET    /forums/:id(.:format)                  forums#show
                     PATCH  /forums/:id(.:format)                  forums#update
                     PUT    /forums/:id(.:format)                  forums#update
                     DELETE /forums/:id(.:format)                  forums#destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just pass the comment or post as a local to the partial?

For the comment on the comment:

```
<%= render "shared/comment_form", locals: { commentable: @comment } %>
```

For the comment on the post:

```
<%= render "shared/comment_form", locals: { commentable: @post } %>
```

And then in `shared/_comment_form`:

```
<div id="comment-form" class="form-group">
  <%= form_for @comment, remote: true, url: post_comments_path(@post)  do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, required: true, rows: 5, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_id, :value => commentable.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_type, :value => commentable.class.name %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<span id="add-comment">Add a comment</span>
```

I'm not quite sure about the path in there, you have `post_comments_path(@post)` but comments on comments won't have a direct relationship with the post so this won't work. You might have to change this depending on your routing.

Comment: It gets me closer. I didn't know you could pass locals like that. Would it be possible to add an erb `if` block to decide what `form_for` line to pass in depending on the name of the local? Would that break the form or am I totally off base here?

Comment: Also, I've updated my original post with my relevant routes.

Comment: The problem is that in your routes, you have comments nested under posts, but this assumes that every comment is related to a post, which is not the case for comment comments, right? Can you show your `PostsController`?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to have an `if` block to change the `form_for`. Do you have different fields depending on if the comment is a "post comment" or a "comment comment"? If so you can switch on `commentable.is_a?(Post)` or `commentable.is_a?(Comment)`.